# Hibernate 6 - "Not a managed type" error setting enum on entity using CriteriaUpdate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

We have been upgrading from hibernate 5 to hibernate 6 and it has been such a PITA due so so many changes made to hibernate.

We have an entity below:

```
@Entity(name = "Entity")
public class EntityImpl {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="REASON_VAL")
    @Convert(converter = ReasonConverter.class)
    private Reason reason;

    ....
    ....
```

Reason is a simple enum class. I have a custom converter implemented for it also. We use a CriteriaUpdate to bulk change some records and set the Reason value to null using the following:

```
CriteriaUpdate<EntityImpl> cq = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(EntityImpl.class);

Root<EntityImpl> root = cq.from(EntityImpl.class);
cq.set(root.<Reason> get("reason"), cb.nullLiteral(Reason.class));
```

When we execute this we get the following:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Not a managed type: class com.model.enums.Reason
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:371) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:234) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:163) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jdk.proxy4.$Proxy321.setMultipleState(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.service.ServiceImpl.setMultipleState(ServiceImpl.java:9842) ~[component-impl-10.2.3.jar:10.2.3]
    at com.service.ServiceImpl.performBulkOperation(ServiceImpl.java:6287) ~[component-impl-10.2.3.jar:10.2.3]
    at com.service.ServiceImpl.lambda$bulkCancelStrategies$8(ServiceImpl.java:6168) ~[component-impl-10.2.3.jar:10.2.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at com.service.ServiceImpl.bulkCancelStrategies(ServiceImpl.java:6167) [component-impl-10.2.3.jar:10.2.3]
    at com.service.ServiceImpl.bulkCancel(ServiceImpl.java:9285) [component-impl-10.2.3.jar:10.2.3]
    at com.service.ServiceImpl.cancelOrders(ServiceImpl.java:9115) [component-impl-10.2.3.jar:10.2.3]
    at com.service.ServiceImpl.cancelOrders(ServiceImpl.java:8921) [component-impl-10.2.3.jar:10.2.3]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) [spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698) [spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at com.service.ServiceImpl$$SpringCGLIB$$0.cancelOrders(<generated>) [component-impl-10.2.3.jar:10.2.3]
    at com.trading.services.impl.ClientAPIImpl.cancelOrders(ClientAPIImpl.java:1598) [trading-impl-10.2.3.jar:10.2.3]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) [spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) [spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) [spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) [spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) [spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) [spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) [spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) [spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702) [spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at com.trading.services.impl.ClientAPIImpl$$SpringCGLIB$$0.cancelOrders(<generated>) [trading-impl-10.2.3.jar:10.2.3]
    at com.trading.services.mdp.CancelOrderMDP.processCancelOrder(CancelOrderMDP.java:275) [trading-impl-10.2.3.jar:10.2.3]
    at com.trading.services.mdp.CancelOrderMDP.processMessage(CancelOrderMDP.java:136) [trading-impl-10.2.3.jar:10.2.3]
    at com.trading.services.mdp.CancelOrderMDP$1.doInTransaction(CancelOrderMDP.java:95) [trading-impl-10.2.3.jar:10.2.3]
    at com.trading.services.mdp.CancelOrderMDP$1.doInTransaction(CancelOrderMDP.java:91) [trading-impl-10.2.3.jar:10.2.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) [spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at com.trading.services.mdp.CancelOrderMDP.onMessage(CancelOrderMDP.java:91) [trading-impl-10.2.3.jar:10.2.3]
    at com.service.messaging.mdp.MDPTask.run(MDPTask.java:138) [broker-messaging-impl-10.2.3.jar:10.2.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.model.enums.DIReason
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.nullLiteral(SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.java:1089) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.nullLiteral(SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at com.repository.RecordRepository.setMultipleState(RecordRepository.java:313) ~[limitorder-repository-impl-10.2.3.jar:10.2.3]
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:732) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:83) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 52 more
```

I've attempted to create a custom EnumType by extending org.hibernate.type.EnumType and overriding the method:

```
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, DIReason value, int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
```

Then annotating like below:

```
@Column(name="REASON_VAL")
@Convert(converter = ReasonConverter.class)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Type(ReasonType.class)
private Reason reason;
```

But this has no effect either. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure your enum is getting scanned. Check the below tutorial. https://javatute.com/spring-boot/not-a-managed-type-entity-spring-boot/

Comment: I tried that already also and it made no difference. Also to note that "Reason" is not an entity anyway. It worked prior to the upgrade to spring boot 3 and hibernate 6 and all calls to the entity containing it work as long as it's not using the Criteria API. Using standard JPA repos works fine.

Comment: What have you changed for spring upgrade? (Why don't you show imports/fully qualified class names?(javax -> jakarta;))

Comment: I'm facing the same issue now after migrating to spring boot 3. Do you know a solution in the meanwhile?

Comment: It seems to be fixed in hibernate 6.2.7 however they broke selecting nullLiteral for enums with the fix.